# Web based collaborative editing using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am looking to create a web based collaborative editor (like Google docs but very basic. 2 or more users editing a page). I am using the Spring MVC framework and wanted to know the best way to start this. 
Should I use AJAX, if so can you point me in the right direction?
Otherwise, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need spring's websocket support. Go through the spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) 
You may need to create a handler which will be mapped with websocket in spring like this.

```
<websocket:handlers>
        <websocket:mapping path="/myHandler" handler="myHandler"/>
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    </websocket:handlers>
```

Or  you can create a web-scoket configuration with annotation like below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
```